# POST data in Play framework 2.2

Tags: scala, post, playframework-2.2, slick-2.0

What is the quickest way to get single value from POST data without using Forms?

I tried `request.body`, but it has no methods, so it is not possible to do something like this: `request.body.get("param")` or `request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("param")`.

I suppose it has something to do with the fact that it is a **DBAction from Slick** not just a regular Action.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not HTML expert but doesn't it depend on type of body ? If it's JSON then you could query it like it but what if it's simple text? or gif?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the body type. There are parsers for each type (json, text, etc).

Comment: On `DBAction` I see the following method: `def apply[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(requestHandler: DBSessionRequest[A] => SimpleResult)` So you could try adding a BodyParser here too: `DBAction(parse.json){ request => ... }`. Body parsers are detailed here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaBodyParsers

Comment: There were some additional issues, but this was basically the answer. Thanks!